# Issues with wifi channels

Tags: wifi-configuration

I'm in trouble with settings of my access point. My WLAN is set on channel 6 - 20 MHz wide. A neighbor of mine has a new access point set on channel 3 - 40 MHz wide so overlaps on mine. I changed my access point to channel 11 and my devices have trouble to connect. No other wlan. Moreover they have a slower connection. Is it possible that changed channel can create issues? The things are worse if I expand my channel to 40 MHz?
What's happen? Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: You should never use 40MHz wide channels on 2.4GHz Wi-Fi in crowded areas or when the link isn't stable. It decreases link stability and is very neighbour unfriendly.

Comment: Oh... Thanks I didn't know that. 40 MHz is better for 5 GHz?

Comment: Ok I reset to 20MHz wide channel. But I'm pretty sure that connection speed is lower on channel 11 than channel 6. Maybe?

Comment: Wider channels go better with 5GHz wifi as there is a greater likelihood of having free channels. As far as your issue goes: can you post a screenshot of a program like Inssider?

Comment: Honestly, you are very limited with 2.4GHz because of the 3 non-overlapping channels (1, 6, 11) and the fact that it is very congested.  If channel 6 (20MHz) worked better than channel 11 (20Mhz) - I would suggest that you stay on channel 6.  5GHz would be a better choice for you, see if you can migrate to 5GHz.

Comment: I apologise AdmiralFreebee but I don't know how to add a screenshot. I try to depict the situation. The channel 1 and 3 are congested by other network that use 40MHz band so overlapp a little on the channel 6. So I decided to move to channel 11 where I am alone. But the link is instable. So I decided to return to channel 6 at 54 Mbps and all go right. I cannot understand.